# Passing i-- expression as parameter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, parameters, expression

The following code appends a new div each 1 second at the body. I do not understand why the call newDiv(i--) works and newDiv(i-1) does not. I would accept an answer that gives me a clear explanation.

I know that i-- equals i=i-1.

"Does not work" means, that the behaviour of newDiv(i-1) appends a new div containing a constant number like 9,9,9,9,9,... to the body.

Correct behaviour would a decreasing number: i.e. 9,8,7,...,0. Which is done by newDiv(i--)

```
function newDiv(n) {
    var bodyObj = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = n;
    bodyObj.appendChild(div);

    if(n===0) {
    var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    h1.innerHTML = 'Hallo World';
    bodyObj.appendChild(h1);
    }
}

var i=0;
while(i<10) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    newDiv(i--); // i-1 does not work, placing i-- before does not work either.
    }, i*1000);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Define "does not work".

Comment: i-- is not eqiuvalent to i-1. it is equivalent to i = i-1.

Comment: `i-1` doesn't assign to `i`, while `i--` does.  You should read through documentation on [javascript arithmetic operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Arithmetic).

Comment: if you're doing proper DOM node work using create/append/etc, don't ever use `innerHTML`. Use `textContent` to set text content. That said, what does "does not work" mean to you? Also, Rather than using a `while`, it would make more sense to schedule "the next one to create" only if the previous one succeeded, so that you can easily cancel the process as well, using a function that creates a div, then has a setTimeout to itself for building the next div.

Answer (score -1):

While using `i-1` you're not actually setting the `i` var.

`i--` equals to `i=i-1`

Comment: `i--` is not equivalent to `i=i-1`.  `i--` returns the original value before decrementing.  `i=i-1` is more like `--i`.

Answer (score -1):

`i--` works because it's actually mutates the variable while `i - 1` just "echos" the result of the expression but don't modify the `i`. I recommend to read this chapter of YDKJS if you really want to understand your snippet:
https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch5.md#statements--expressions